Use value from textbox to var
I want to use a value from a textbox in this code, there subjectId is
            var body = @"{
            ""requestId"": ""requestId"",
            ""subjectId"": ""subjectId"" 
            }";

I have tried different things but gets error all the time.
Tried like this
string number = personnummer.Text;          
  var body = @"{
            ""requestId"": ""requestId"",
            ""subjectId"": " + number + " 
            }";


tried like this? string number = personnummer.Text;
var body = @"{ ""requestId"": ""requestId"", ""subjectId"": """ + number + @""" }";

Care to tell us the error message? Looks like the code is correct.

Why are you (trying to) Json-Serializing manually?

In C# 11 and later, you can do it with Raw String Literals and String Interpolation:
var body = $$"""
           {
               "requestId": "requestId",
               "subjectId": {{number}}
           }
           """;

In older versions this would also be possible, just slightly less readable.
But why not just use Json Serialization:
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static JsonSerializerOptions jso = new JsonSerializerOptions(){
        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
        WriteIndented = true
    };
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        string number = "ID FROM TEXTBOX";
        var req = new SubjectRequest("requestId", number);
        
        var body = JsonSerializer.Serialize(req, jso);
        
        Console.WriteLine(body);
    }
}

public sealed record SubjectRequest( string RequestId, string SubjectId );

Output:

{
  "requestId": "requestId",
  "subjectId": "ID FROM TEXTBOX"
}

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ieDG4V
